# Formula relating dimension of fiber of morphism between varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a morphism of (irreducible) varieties, where the dimension of every fiber dim$f^{-1}(y)=n$ is the same. Must it follow that dim$X=$ dim$Y+n$?

The reason I am asking this is that this is a theorem in some notes I am reading, but I am sure the proof presented is problematic, yet I cannot seem to patch the errors. However this does seem geometrically intuitive... Any help is appreciated!

Comment: There is a dense open subset of $Y$ where the fibers have pure dimension $\dim X - \dim Y$. So yes, it must follow. This is a very important fact so it should be in most books. I'm sure it's in Shafarevich, for example.

Comment: See Theorem 9.9 in Milne's notes: http://jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ag.html

Comment: @Hoot Thanks for the reference!

Comment: I also want to point out that results of this flavor exist in linear algebra and differential geometry (here you probably have to consider very special types of differentiable maps to get nice statements; varieties are much more rigid, which is why the subject is so fun). I don't think it's so unintuitive: if $X$ is going to map somewhere else then it spends some of its dimension on the image and some of its dimension on the fibers. The theorem says that for the most part this expectation is correct.